# Синтаксический контроль javascript cordova в androidstudio?

Tags: javascript, android-studio, cordova

Подскажите, как  сделать синтаксический контроль java script  в проекте на cordova  android studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С использованием инструментов для статической проверки кода, таких как [ESLint](https://eslint.org/).

```
 npm install eslint --save-dev
```

Создайте файл конфигурации ESLint в корневой директории вашего проекта. Вы можете использовать команду eslint --init, чтобы создать конфигурацию, или создать .eslintrc.js файл вручную и настроить правила согласно вашим предпочтениям. Пример .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: "eslint:recommended",
  rules: {
    // Ваши настройки правил здесь
  },
};
```

Добавьте скрипты в package.json:
В файле package.json вашего проекта добавьте скрипты для запуска ESLint.

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint .",
  "lint-fix": "eslint --fix ."
}
```

Запустите синтаксический контроль:
Теперь вы можете запустить синтаксический контроль вашего JavaScript кода, выполнив команду:

```
npm run lint
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы ESLint автоматически исправлял некоторые ошибки, выполните команду:

```
npm run lint-fix
```